# how does "ofy().save().entities( )" and "ofy().save().entitiy()" in Objectify works

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I want to know how does `ofy().save().entities()` is differ from `ofy().save().entity()`.

I know that the `ofy().save().entities()` will save multiple entites when `ofy().save().entity()` will save only the given entity.

My doubt is what will be the different to store 10 entities with `ofy().save().entity()` using 10 times and saving all 10 entites with `ofy().save().entities()` at once.

1. What would be the write operation for both operations?
2. how the iteration will be happen?
3. how long it will take ?

Thanks in Advance. I am very beginner to this. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Billed write operations are per-entity and will be the same either way.

Calling multiple separate `save()` operations will take significantly longer than a single batch `save()` because it incurs the latency of a separate RPC request each time. Always prefer batch operations if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @stickfigure. consider this scenerio If I want to update the single property in list of entities i will iterate the list of entites and update the property using Entity.setWhatever() method and then if i call saveMultipleEntites() will it be like iterating the whole entites again for saving in a batch

Comment: I didn't quite follow that, but whenever you are doing an update (load + change + save), you almost always need a transaction to avoid updates stepping on each other.